# Change drawer icon

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm using `DrawerLayout` and want to change programmatically the icon.

Here my code :

```
private void initDrawerLayout(@DrawableRes int icon)
{
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, icon, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
        {
            // ... do stuffs ...
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            // ... do stuffs ...
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
 }
```

In `OnCreate` Activity method I call this method : initDrawerLayout(R.drawable.drawer);

Then, in some fragments I need to change this icon... So I tried to call the same method with an other `Drawable` by it doesn't works...

Comment: You may need to learn about navigation drawer [HERE](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/). After you learn it, you can change the icon using `navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[title_index], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(icon_index, -1)));`. The `title_index` is based on `string-array` list. And the icon_index is based on `array` list. On that site, see step 2.

Comment: Thanks, but when I speak about icon, it is icon called "ic_drawer.png" in your example...